# Handle multiple asynchronous responses

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous

I am a web developer and writing services for android. The android developer, whom with I am working, is sending multiple async calls to the server, and asking me to send a service code with in the response of each service, as he will able to decide about a particular response belongs to which service that he sent before.

Is'nt there a way in android to keep track the responses of multiple async calls? Why should the server tell to android that which service is served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think their is no need of service code to keep track of the response-request pair, because if 5 threads sends the 5 different request, then, all of them receive their responses only.

Order of retrieval of response may vary.
Lets assume a condition,

1. ThreadA sends requestA.
2. ThreadB sends requestB.

Then,

1. ThreadA receives responseA only.
2. ThreadB receives responseB only.

Order variation:
ThreadB response may come before ThreadA.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the server to send any code . He could send each http request using IntentService with a key. On each response from your server, he puts the key in a bundle,  compare it and do what he wants.

See this code : https://github.com/JCERTIFLab/jcertif-android-2013/blob/master/src/com/jcertif/android/fragments/InitialisationFragment.java

Comment: Does IntentService allow multiple parallel requests?

Comment: Yes ! Each incoming request is handled in a separated thread.